# Cannot grant role to user in Postgres on Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure

I have a Postgres 11 instance on Azure and I am trying to execute simple script to create and assign role to user:

```
CREATE ROLE testRole;
GRANT testRole TO my_user;
```

Although after i run this i get:

```
ERROR:  only superusers can grant role "pg_execute_server_program"
SQL state: 42501
```

I am not sure why does it even want to grant `pg_execute_server_program` role even though i am not assigning it anywhere to `testRole`. I don't even care about this role and would gladly create user without it.

This code was working without problems until Microsoft decided to bump up minor postgres version from 11.11 to 11.12. Any ideas what I am doing wrong in this case?

Comment: They broke something with a version upgrade, in MS Q&A forum there are a few threads on the same issue ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/712821/azure-postgresql-database-cannot-grant-role-to-my.html), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/709457/minor-version-upgrade-of-managed-postgres-does-not.html)). MS employees claim they're working on the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug introduced by Microsoft. It seems to be fixed now. I created fresh Postgres instance and it works.

If you are not able to simply recreate Postgres instance, scaling it up and down again should also fix it (although I haven't tried that)

I got following answer from Microsoft support:

> The fix was rolled out and the issue should now be fixed. Could you
> please try again?
>
> If the error persists, please scale up the server and then back down
> again, or down and up, and try again.